# Error on Update Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm having some trouble here.

When I try update my entity, this exception is thrown:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

I searched everywhere, but no success!

The model:

```
public class Projeto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFim { get; set; }
    public string NumeroContrato { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    public virtual Contato Contato { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
}

public class Funcionario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAdmicao { get; set; }
    public string NomePai { get; set; }
    public string NomeMae { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Projeto> Projetos { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller:

Update Method:

```
public void Salvar(Projeto projeto)
{
    AppContext _dao = new AppContext();
    projeto.Cliente = _dao.Cliente.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == projeto.Cliente.Id);
    _dao.Entry(projeto).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    _dao.SaveChanges();
}
```

The method "Salvar" is not equal to this, I made a summary. but this is what happens!

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your `FirstOrDefault()` method returns any object at all:

```
projeto.Cliente = _dao.Cliente.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == projeto.Cliente.Id);
```

Are you sure that your `projeto.Cliente.Id` is set to appropriate Id (or there is any `Id` set at all?).

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that returns a valid "Cliente".

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the `projeto` to the context first and then make a change:

```
// Attach:
_dao.Entry(projeto).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Attached;
// Change:
projeto.Cliente = _dao.Cliente.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == projeto.Cliente.Id);
```

Also, make sure `projeto.Cliente` is loaded before you modify it, else the change tracker won't notice the change.

Note that you could also set a primitive foreign key value `ClienteId`, if you'd make that part of the model. It would save you a few loads of `Cliente` objects. (Look for *foreign key associations vs. independent associations*).

Comment: It does not work. I tried that. The "project" is just a model. and has also tried to insert a foreign key, not also works of the same error.